# encrypted register and login passwords gone wrong

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, passwords, encryption

I have a sign up script:

```
function NewUser() 
{ 
        $fullname = $_POST['name']; 
        $userName = $_POST['user']; 
        $email = $_POST['email']; 
        $password = $_POST['pass'];
        $confirm_password = $_POST['cpass'];
        $salt = 'a salt(not in my real script)';
        $password = crypt($password, $salt);
        $query = "INSERT INTO WebsiteUsers (fullname,userName,email,pass) VALUES ('$fullname','$userName','$email','$password')"; 
        $data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error()); 
        if($data) 
        { 
        echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED..."; 
        } 
    }
```

Which works perfectly, it stores everything inclusive the encrypted password.
I also have a check login code:

```
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT pass FROM $tbl_name WHERE userName='$myusername' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql); 

if (crypt($user_input, $password) == $password){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

There is something going wrong in this code that is blocking my login_success.php it will say that is the wrong username or password, I know it is my password that is going wrong with the encryption. Can someone help me debugging this code so it will see the encrypted password in the right way. Because I am testing the websites login but it doesn't work because(what I think) it can't see the encrypted password right.(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: what is the size of password field in table ?

Comment: what do you mean? @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: do you mean this: http://puu.sh/83sSJ.png ? @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: i mean the table where u have have pass field ?

Comment: yes first thing make it varchar (100) and then re-add a new user. Then u need to fix the code and need to retrieve the password to a variable and then do the check.

Comment: You're assigning and checking the wrong variables. You're checking if the user's password is the same as your DB password, unless that's what you want to do.

Comment: i have made it 100 and added a new user called chicken with password chicken, the encrypted password is:$2Aed0QGEkH/E

Comment: @Fred-ii- so what should I do?

Comment: Whatever you're doing here, **STOP**. You're doing it wrong. This is nowhere even close to doing a proper user authentication system. Please, do not reinvent the wheel and end up with a square one. Read up on [proper security practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) or you will create a site that's extremely vulnerable. A better approach for a new application is to pick a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) that meets your needs and use a tested, field-proven authentication system.

Comment: @tadman i am new indeed and i don't know much about it and that's why i want help with my login code

Comment: @user3442233 Honestly, burn this to the ground and start over. You cannot use `mysql_query` in new applications. It's way too risky. Your short example here is full of [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/), and it's completely reckless to pursue this way of developing. It's okay to be a new developer, but you're making some serious mistakes here and they could cost you dearly. It's better to use trusted, tested code and build on top of that solid foundation, that's what development frameworks do. They give you a big head start.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds harsh, but it would take literally seconds for an [injection testing tool](http://sqlmap.org/) to bust your site wide open and leave you in the awkward position of having to explain to all your users that your database has been compromised. Nobody wants to go through that.

Comment: Try `if (crypt($mypassword, $password) == $password)` and as Tadman mentions, use his recommendations. @user3442233 Tadman tells it like it is, nothing personal am sure. He means well ;-)

Comment: @tadman so you say i should try using the 3 links you send me? thanks :) i will try it out, maybe i understand it and maybe not p.s. just turned 17

Comment: I've heard that [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is a good place to start if you're new to PHP and aren't a seasoned developer. It has a [built-in authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) that's really easy to use. Getting this stuff right when you do it all yourself is really, really hard.

Comment: Well, if my comment about using `if (crypt($mypassword, $password) == $password)` solved it, sure since that's the original issue. If not, no point in doing so unless it did solve it. @nickuid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach to creating a site with an authentication system is to make use of a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) that already has one built in.

A good example is [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) which has a really robust [authentication platform](http://laravel.com/docs/security) that you can use right out of the box.

Comment: It's for anything that can run PHP.

Comment: the laravel cause i see : /usr/local/bin and the word terminal, typical for linux

Comment: There's [installation instructions](http://laravel.com/docs/installation) that describe how to install on Windows. The procedure is largely the same, substituting "cmd" for "terminal".

Comment: it is no application it is a website if you didnt know that yet

Comment: I'm using "application" here to describe anything with PHP code.

Comment: yes i know laravel is for applications right? i only wanted a login system for my website.... so people can only enter certain areas of my website with only a account, it didn't need to have a so secure way of php cause it mostly is for my friends so at most a group of 40 people, and if there came more people i can always upgrade my code. so yeah website not application

Comment: The super hack way is an `.htaccess` file. Anything beyond that is going to need some kind of CMS at the very least. If you have code protecting content, it's technically an application since each page will have logic that executes vs. static files.